# Find the smallest loss in multiobject detection

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network

I am detecting multiple ( up to 10 ) objects on video image or anything.

input is image and labels for that image, for example

```
[[box1],[box2],[box3],[00...],....]
```

Each box is represented as xmin, ymin , xmax, and ymax.

What is causing my trouble is situation, when my output of CNN is something like this:

```
[[somewhat close to box3],[something],[something...]]
```

How to treat situation like this? If i dont treat it the input box will be compared to "somewhat close to box3" box. Which will result in big loss, thus the network will learn wrongly. However if my input b3 was compared to "somewhat close to box3" the network would learn much better.

Currently what i am doing is:

```
20 times ( epoch size)
1) Train network epoch size = 1
2) Test the network on trained data
3) Calculate IOU for all combinations of boxes.
4) Sort the boxes in my input label according to IOU ( so if input box 2 will have biggest IOU with output box 1 , put input box on 1st position in input label )
```

However, this seem not to work as excted, specially when IOU in first N epochs is 0.

How could i deal with this? Thanks for help.

edit:

My exact shape of output is

(10,4) vector e.g

```
[[xmin,ymin,xamx,ymax],  // first bounding box of object
 [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]   // second..
 .... ]
```

If no object is present in box , the box has all properties set to 0

Comment: Something in the lines of: calculate all distances for all pairs, sequentially select (and eliminate) the pairs with the smallest distance. After selecting the pairs, calculate their losses.

Comment: Can you share the exact shape of the outputs and what each dimension means?

Comment: @DanielMöller i will provide it tomorrow

Comment: @DanielMöller i have provided shape of output